# Cirq : Reference for Toffoli decomposition

Tags: gate-synthesis, cirq

I was trying to find a reference for the 7 T-gate decomposition of the Toffoli gate given by Cirq. The decomposition originates from the the one used for CCZPowGate as given in the doc string here

https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/cirq-core/cirq/ops/three_qubit_gates.py#L100

This is mentioned as an adjacency respecting decomposition by which I understand that the CNOTs are nearest neighbour

Most of the literature I have seen on Toffoli gate decompositions seem to use long range CNOTs for example in Neilson and Chuang or here

https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.04764 .

Does anyone have an idea about the source of the decomposition used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the one who added this code to Cirq. I found that decomposition as part [self-answering a question from 2018](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/minimum-number-of-cnots-for-toffoli-with-non-adjacent-controls). I found it by messing around in Quirk, trying different strategies.

Norbert Schuch has a comment on the answer saying the decomposition appears in his thesis in 2002. I wasn't able to get his thesis to check as the link he gave is dead now, but I don't doubt he also found it or that the original discovery predates mine by more than a decade.

Comment: Thanks Craig, that is very helpful!