# How to decompose 4 qubits Toffoli-gate into two-qubits CNOT gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Can I decompose a 4-qubit Toffoli gate into two qubit CNOT gate without ancillary state?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

A circuit is given e.g. in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4090/491) to a closely related question.